# Differential of Derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have encountered with a problem, and I can't follow the intermediate steps. Consider the following differential equation:

$$ y^{\prime \prime} = -2y + f(y)-0.5y^3 $$

Here, the first derivative is expressed as the following integral:

$$ (y^{\prime})^2 = 2\int_0^{y^\prime} y^\prime dy^\prime  $$

Without giving the details of the intermediate steps, this equation is converted into the following equation using the differential equation given above:

$$ (y^{\prime})^2 = -2 \int_{Y}^{y} \left( 2y - f(y)+0.5y^3 \right) dy$$

where $Y$ is the maximum value of $y$ when $y^\prime$ is zero. Here, I would like to learn how to express differential of a derivative $ dy^\prime $ in terms of $dy$, and end up with the above equation. If I am not wrong, the following equality must hold:

$$ y^\prime dy^\prime = y^{\prime \prime} dy $$

How can I prove this equality? I am confused to think a differential like $ dy^\prime = d(\frac{dy}{dx}) $. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Didnt you make a sign mistahe here $(y^{\prime})^2 = -2 \int_{Y}^{y} \left( -2y + f(y)-0.5y^3 \right) dy$ ?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y^\prime dy^\prime = y^{\prime \prime} dy$$
Simply because:
$$y''dy=\left (\dfrac {dy'}{dx} \right )dy=y'dy'$$

---

Note that 
$$y^{\prime \prime} = -2y + f(y)-0.5y^3$$
Multiply by $2y'$
$$2y'y^{\prime \prime} = -4yy' + 2y'f(y)-y^3y'$$
$$(y'^2)'= -4yy' + 2y'f(y)-y^3y'$$
And integrate since $2y''y'=(y'^2)'$
$$\int (y'^2)'dx=\int ( -4yy' + 2y'f(y)-y^3y')dx$$
But since $y'dx=dy$ we simplify the integrand:
$$y'^2=\int ( -4y + 2f(y)-y^3)dy$$
$$y'^2=-2\int ( 2y -f(y)+\dfrac 12 y^3)dy$$

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome @nicomedian

Comment: I added some lines I hope its more clear @nicomedian

Comment: It is crystal clear right now. Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: You're welcome @nicomedian